# Creating a Base Component in Typescript using Abstract

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a base component with some default methods used in list page, so this is my ts file:

```
export abstract class BaselistComponent<T> implements OnInit {
  source: LocalDataSource = new LocalDataSource();

  constructor(private service: BasecrudService<T>,
              private notification: NotificationService) {
  }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.findRecords().subscribe((data: T[]) => {
      this.source.load(data);
    });
  }
}
```

And now i have the Component that use this base:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-unidade',
  templateUrl: './unidade.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./unidade.component.scss'],
})
export class UnidadeComponent extends BaselistComponent<Unidade> {

   constructor(service: UnidadeService, notification: NotificationService) {
    super(service, notification);
  }
}
```

When i try to execute my APP i got `Cannot read property 'findRecords' of undefined` i know this error occur because `this.service` is undefined but i don't know why, i already declared it.

This is my service base:

```
export abstract class BasecrudService<T> {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: Adapter<T>) {
  }

  abstract getPrefixURL(): string;

  findRecords(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/${this.getPrefixURL()}/pagina/0`).pipe(
      map((data: any) => data.registros.map(item => this.adapter.adapt(item))),
    );
  }
}
```

And the service Impl:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UnidadeService extends BasecrudService<Unidade> {

  constructor(http: HttpClient, adapter: Adapter<Unidade>) {
    super(http, adapter);
  }

  getPrefixURL(): string {
    return 'unidades';
  }

}
```

**Edit 1**

This is my `console.log(this)`, note that my `service` is undefined

[image]

**Edit 2**
This is my project complete source: https://github.com/rlanhellas/safepark-front

Comment: Works fine here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e4zvvp?file=src%2Fapp%2Funidade.ts

Comment: could you provide more info about your environment? eg. angular version and others

Comment: I edited the post with more information, i'm using angular 7

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I have no ideia why you code works and mine not.

Comment: are you providing any of the services (abstract or concrete) in any module?

Comment: Not, i"'m just using the decorator with providedIn

Comment: any change of creating a small reproduction in stackblitz?

Comment: Yes, one moment.

Comment: The weird thing is that angular is injecting "something" for the service token, but throws null reference when trying to call an instance method...

Comment: I don't know how but works in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m9fjtm

Comment: can you look at `this.service.findRecords` and before that add `console.log(this)` to see if `this` is actually the component, and then inspect the component in the console and see if it contains the prototype of the base class.

Comment: You might want to restart `ng serve` so that your compile caches are cleared.

Comment: @cgTag i edited my post and inserted the "console.log(this)", as you can see the service is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that you use interface in Angular DI.

**unidate.service.ts**

```
export class UnidadeService extends BasecrudService<Unidade> {

  constructor(http: HttpClient, adapter: Adapter<Unidade>) {
                                         ^^^^^^^
    super(http, adapter);
  }
}
```

which results in DI error so you don't get `UnidadeService` initialized